# How to minify JavaScript & CSS using Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minify, pagespeed

I'm currently using Rails 4. My settings:

**production.rb**

```
  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
```

My understanding is Rails 4 is supposed to minify JS and CSS however when I run Page Speed Insights, I'm being told I need to minify my JS & CSS.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get my Rails 4 app to minify JS and CSS and make Google PageSpeed happy?

Comment: Does your Gemfile include the `sass-rails` gem?

Comment: Yes it does `gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'` -- I'm hosting on heroku. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Are you sure its not a false positive? Have you tried manually looking at the compiled assets in production?

Answer (score 2):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-compression

If your Gemfile includes sass-rails, CSS will be minified by default as long as `config.assets.compress = true` in your production.rb

To compress JS, you can use
`config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier`

Make sure `uglifier` is in your Gemfile.